# If I have bitcoins in blockchain.info wallet, can I transfer it to my local bitcoin account wallet?

Tags: blockchain.info

If I have bitcoins in a blockchain.info wallet, can I transfer it to my local bitcoin wallet? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Get a Bitcoin address from the wallet you want to send to and then send to that address.